# Open PDF file in android application

Tags: android

I have to open PDF file which is already stored in my SD card.
    Open PDF file in current application with Zoom functionality, Search functionality, Page previous-next option functionality and also other option display while PDF is open.
    If need to add any custom library then i am able to add, i am use PDF viewer library, mupdf library but not get proper response form these libraries so i want to make changes in my current application.
so please help me if any one have new idea for open PDF in current application

(Sorry of my poor English)
    Thank you.

Comment: muPDF is great library for opening PDF. What is issue with mPDF??

Comment: you can download http://mupdf.com/downloads library and integrate that in your app.

Comment: @ChandrakantDvivedi i am using muPDF library but the issue is if PDF file is large(upto 10 to 20 mb) then my app is crashed when scroll PDF pages.

Comment: Have you used ZoanZapata ? It is also a great library.

Comment: @ChandrakantDvivedi yes i am using this also but do not get success, sorry but have any other idea??

Answer (score 1):

I have researched below libraries for view PDF , please check below all libraries

```
PDF Viewers


PDF Viewer Library
Name : PDF Viewer Library
Link   :  https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
Desc   : This library is under LGPL licence


PDF Viewer Android Offline
Name : PDF Viewer Android Offline
Link   :  https://github.com/bitfield66/PdfViewerAndroid_Offline
Desc  : This library will take MuPDF Library as base and modified it under GPL Licence


PDF Viewer (Under General Public Licence)
Name : PDF Viewer
Link   : https://github.com/rameshakulapc/PDFViewer
Desc  : This library is also under GPL Licence
Play  : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.pdfviewer3


Android PDF Viewers
Name : Android PDF Viewer
Link   :  https://github.com/chintanvyas89/android-pdf-viewer
Desc   :  This library contains three folders apv library, muPDF, PdfViewer . Pdf Viewer is example


Android PDF Viewer (MuPDF)
Name : Android PDF Viewer
Link   :  http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Pdf/Download_Free_code_Android_Pdf_Viewer_Library.htm
Desc  :  MuPDF is open source under GPL License
```

You can also try with below link it also works for me and integrated it in one of my application .

https://code.google.com/r/sylvaincairol-kkkk/source/browse/pdfview/?name=v_0.2.6&r=85a0695dff20bded996822bc9395e69b7af1b2fa

Comment: Thanks you @Android Weblineindia, I search on all above library and let you replay

Comment: I want to use  https://github.com/rameshakulapc/PDFViewer but its very tough to understand how it works...

Comment: sorry , i have not used that library . i have searched this library during my investigation . please check the source code you will get idea